# What is the backstory to New York's economy in The Caves of Steel?

Tags: isaac-asimov, the-caves-of-steel

In Asimov's *The Caves of Steel*, when people get a promotion, their living conditions improve. Bailey had a certain amount of rations for his tobacco. When he was promoted, his living quarters were improved with an added sink. There were communal kitchens. Traveling outside of one's neighborhood required paperwork.

In universe, did Asimov ever write any short stories providing more backstory to how New York came to have this economic system?

Out of universe, did Asimov ever cite what countries inspired him to write these?

Comment: I think this was pure futurism - anticipating the possible consequences of an ever-increasing population.  The premise is that the economic system was adopted out of sheer necessity, as the only one that would work with so many people.

Comment: This is literally how the USSR's system of communism worked.

Comment: FWIW, Asimov was no stranger to crowded conditions. He grew up in various small apartments in Brooklyn. From the introduction of *The Early Asimov, Volume 1*: "we lived in an apartment in which all the rooms were in a line and the only way of getting from the living room to the bedroom of my parents, or of my sister, or of my brother, was by going through *my* bedroom. My bedroom was therefore frequently gone through, and the fact that I might be in the throes of creation meant nothing to anyone."

Comment: J. G. Ballard's [Billennium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billennium_(short_story)) is the a memorable story about ultra-dense future living. Really nails the claustrophobia, for me.